# jQuery - inArray with ID of elements - 'else' not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, slideup

I create a set of questions and answers.

HTML:

```
<div class="faq" id="faq_1">
    <div class="question"><p class="qtext">Theard</p><span class="qshow">+</span></div>
    <div class="answer">

        <div class="faq" id="faq_2">
            <div class="question"><p class="qtext">Question?</p><span class="qshow">+</span></div>
            <div class="answer" id="faq_2a">
                <p class="aodp">
                    Answer...
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.question').click(function() { ShowFAQ('#' + $(this).parent().attr("id"));   } );

        var faq_arr = [];
        function ShowFAQ(el)
        {
            if($.inArray(el, faq_arr) == -1) faq_arr[el] = 0; //if not exist = set default value.

            if(faq_arr[el] == 0) { $(el + ' .answer:first' ).slideDown(); faq_arr[el] = 1; $(el + ' .qshow:first').text('-'); }
            else { $(el + ' .answer:first').slideUp(); faq_arr[el] = 0; $(el + ' .qshow:first').text('+'); }
        }
```

It's work great, but in the "ShowFAQ" does not execute the code in the 'else'. I know that this is a problem with the "$ .inArray". I do not want to manually print out ID elements. How do I fix this?

Comment: You define `var faq_arr = []` as array, but use it here `faq_arr[el] = 0` as object with key/value. So `$.inArray` will fail here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you can consider, instead of storing the **state** in an `array`, to make use of `.data()` to store the **state** `show` or `hide`, is much easier to maintain and understand.

```js
$('.answer').hide();

$('.question').click(function() {
    ShowFAQ('#' + $(this).parent().attr("id"));
});

function ShowFAQ(el) {
    var $el = $(el);
    var show = $el.data('show'); // get current state

    if (!show) {
       $(el + ' .answer:first').slideDown();
       $(el + ' .qshow:first').text('-');
    } else {
       $(el + ' .answer:first').slideUp();
       $(el + ' .qshow:first').text('+');
    }
   
    $el.data('show', !show); // set oposite to obtain show/hide effect
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="faq" id="faq_1">
  <div class="question">
    <p class="qtext">Theard</p><span class="qshow">+</span>
  </div>
  <div class="answer">
    <div class="faq" id="faq_2">
      <div class="question">
        <p class="qtext">Question?</p><span class="qshow">+</span>
      </div>
      <div class="answer" id="faq_2a">
        <p class="aodp">
          Answer...
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are working with an array, but the arguments is a string, not an index.

What happen is the you are adding a property to the array by doing `faq_arr[el] = 0;`. Unfortunately, `$.inArray` only check into index of the array, properties are ignored.

Instead of working with an array, use an object. Simply do :

```
var faq_arr = {};
```

and :

```
if(typeof faq_arr[el] === 'undefined') faq_arr[el] = 0;
```

Comment: Adding members to an array is actually perfectly fine in JS.

Comment: @Siguza, it is, but `inArray` fail.

Comment: Yes, but because it checks the *values* rather than the *keys*, not because the key is not set.

Comment: @Siguza yeah, I know, that is what i said in the answer ;) *"$.inArray only check into index of the array, properties are ignored."* Also note that i never said it was wrong setting properties to an array!

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code is not working is that

```
$.inArray(el, faq_arr)
```

checks the **values** of `fay_arr` for `el`, but you need to check the **keys**. I suggest:

```
if(faq_arr[el] === undefined)
```

or

```
if(typeof faq_arr[el] === 'undefined')
```

Or see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ly726crh/).

*Edit:* **Karl-André Gagnon**'s answer is also really worth reading, as you should really consider using objects instead of arrays for non-numeric keys. It *will work* with arrays too, and is *technically* fine, but I'm pretty sure it is considered quite **bad practice**.

Comment: *"but at least I consider it rather bad practice."* Don't worry, you are not alone! You can change that to *"but is a rather bad practice."*

Answer (score 0):

```
var faq_arr = [];
function ShowFAQ(el)
{    
    if($.inArray(el, faq_arr) == -1) { 
        $(el + ' .answer:first' ).slideDown(); faq_arr.push(el); $(el + ' .qshow:first').text('-'); 
    }
    else { 
        $(el + ' .answer:first').slideUp(); faq_arr[el] = 0; $(el + ' .qshow:first').text('+'); 
    }
}
```